# How to run server in container and run a cli client to connect it using `docker run`?

Tags: mysql, docker, redis

How to run a server (mysql or redis) in docker and run a cli client in it to connect itself.

```
docker run -it --rm \
--name mysql-container \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword \
-p 3307:3306 \
mysql \
mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306 -p
```

gives error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

```
docker run -it --rm \
--name my-redis \
redis \
redis-cli -h localhost
```

gives error

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused

I'm new to docker. I'm assuming it should run the server and then my client commands. But its not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: These are the commands from their official respective official docker hub pages: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres & https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

Comment: Because you have a `docker run -p 3307:3306` option, you can connect to the database using the MySQL CLI on your host system, `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 ...`; you don't need to do anything Docker-specific for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, but I'm trying not to install anything on my host. I want to run everything from withing docker keeping my system clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to wait for the `mysql-server` and `redis-server` in the `container` to finish booting before executing the login command. Boot time depends on many factors. To be safe, I think you should add `sleep` between commands.

You can try this:

- For MySQL

```
docker run -d --rm \
--name mysql-container \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword \
-p 3307:3306 \
mysql && sleep 5 && \
docker exec -it mysql-container \
bash -c "mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306 -p"
```

- Same, for Redis

```
docker run -d --rm \
--name my-redis \
redis && sleep 5 && \
docker exec -it my-redis \
redis-cli -h localhost
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this already, I want to understand why my command isn't working.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have added explanation to the answer.